# Existence of minimum on unbounded set and function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

I'm having trouble deciding if my proof of this proposition is sufficient. The proposition is,

> Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}^N $ is open and $f:\bar{E} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $\bar{E}$. If $\bar{E}$ is unbounded, assume further that $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $\left\| x \right\| \to + \infty$, $x \in \bar{E}$. Show that $f$ attains a minimum at $z \in \bar{E}$.

I start by showing that the function must be bounded below.

Let $\inf \{ f(x) : x \in \bar{E} \} = m$ and suppose $m = - \infty$. Since $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $\left\| x \right\| \to + \infty$, there must be some compact subset $C \subset \bar{E}$ where $f(C)$ is not bounded below, but since $f$ is continuous and $C$ is compact, this is a contradiction since the continuous image of a compact set must be compact.

Now that I know $m \neq -\infty$, since $m$ is a lower bound for $f$, there exists a sequence $f(x_n) \to m$. I know $x_n$ must be bounded, since otherwise $f(x_n) \to + \infty$, so there is some compact set $X \in \bar{E}$ where $x_n \in X$. Since $f(X)$ must also be compact and therefore also closed, $f(x_n) \to m$ implies there exists $y \in X$ such that $f(x_n) \to m = f(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems good. The basic idea is that you can assume your function $f$ to be larger than some $M$ outside a large ball of radius $R$. Therefore since balls are compact the set $B_R\cap \overline E$ is compact and so your function has a minimum.